# How to limit the log size in c++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

In my application i am creating log file of size 5kb .If i exceeds 5 kb of file size , I have to overwrite the old contents with the help of new contents.

If you have any ideas just share with me.

I also need implementation of this technique in c++

I provide some example

Initially the file look like this

sample.txt

**sample application text
sample**

Assume the above sample text file exceeds 5kb then i added **new** in the source.txt then the file should be like this.

sample.txt

**new sample application text 
sam**

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code I have recently written to implement a simple log-file rotation:

```
std::ostream & libLogging::FileRotationLogSink::GetCurrentStream( 
    std::string::size_type required )
{
    if ( static_cast<std::string::size_type>(m_CurrentStream.tellp( )) + 
        required > m_Limit ) {
        m_CurrentStream.close();
        // remove old backup
        if ( boost::filesystem::exists( m_BackupPath ) ) {
            boost::filesystem::remove( m_BackupPath );
        }
        // backup current logfile
        boost::filesystem::rename( m_LogFilePath, m_BackupPath );
        // open new logfile
        m_CurrentStream.open( m_LogFilePath );
    }
    return m_CurrentStream;
}
```

`required` gives the size of the next message that is to be written to the log. If the file gets too big, it is copied (old backup is overwritten), and a new one is started.

Comment: I think this will remove the previous file and create the new file if the file size exceeds.  What I want is that if the file size exceeds then the pointer will move to the top and replace the current contents  on top and delete the last line in the file and move every contents down.

Comment: @karthik: This is just an example, and should be easy enough to modify to your needs. You can use [`seekp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/seekp/) to reset the write-pointer to the beginning of the file. Or you modify my code to simply skip the backup, and just overwrite the log-file (simple close and open again does that trick).

Comment: @space_cowboy:I check seekp ...by this we can move the position in the file.What i need is if i add some characters in the middle ,it should not be replaced ...like array each characters should be shifted down and the exceeded characters only be deleted

Comment: @karthik: Perhaps you should explain that better in your question, ideally with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Using WinApi, you should

1) Check if file is bigger than a limit using GetFileSize
2) SetFilePointer to 0,0 + SetEndOfFile

Comment: Why use WinApi for something so simple for this? I feel like this is why so much code is hard to port...

Comment: Since the question is tagged MFC, it seems reasonable to me to use Windows API calls.

Comment: @mathepic: because is faster and cleaner and doesn't make the code MFC dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the amount of content you inserted into the log, and check if it is more the 5kb every time. Use a function like:

```
void writeToLog(char c) {
  if(writeIndex == 5000)
    writeIndex =0;
  log[writeIndex] = c;
  writeIndex += 1;
}
```

With this sure you can implement the string writing function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MFC, you can use the CFile class for file management. This class has a GetLength method that return the size of the file.

To overwrite the old content you can manage a buffer of 5000 char representing your file content. And at each file writing you just have to replace file content.

Answer (score 0):

An approach like the following could work:

1. Stream content to file using iostreams (start with a clean file each time you open)
2. After streaming content, use `tellp` to get the last put position (and hence size of file so far).
3. If the position is bigger than 5Kb, then `seekp` to begining of stream...

Answer (score 0):

[log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html) is a good soution that has already solved this problem plus many more you probably haven't yet considered.